# android listview adapter not showing the correct data

Tags: android, listview

I've an app that is used to get rotas for carers. once the carer has logged in he/she can click on a button called getRota. This button calls a webservice and gets that day's rota as the date is passed to this method aswell. Once on the rota page with the rota displayed in the listview i've overridden that activity'd optionsmenu with 3 buttons, next, previous and pick a day. the first 2 button adds one day or deletes one day from a dateTime and then passes it back to the calling class to call the webservice again with the new datetime.

All this works fine until you press the back key whilst viewing the rota. When the back key is pressed, it goes back to the calling activity where you can click getRota, inside this method i always set the dateTime to today. The problem is, when the user clicks get rota, then clicks next, then back key then getrota, todays date should be shown in the listview but the next day's rota is shown. It is like the listview is not being updated with current days rota.

Here's some of the code, i can give more if required.

```
public class GetRota extends NfcBaseActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = GetRota.class.getSimpleName();
    ListView listView;
    Intent intent;
    String callID;

    NfcScannerApplication nfcscannerapplication;
    ArrayList<?> array;
    String needName = "";
    MySimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private DatePicker dpResult;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    String statusField;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;  
    TextView textViewDate; 

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getrotalayout);
        setCurrentDateOnView();

        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        //set titlebar to carer's name
        Cursor cursorCarerName = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromCarer();
        cursorCarerName.moveToLast();
        String carerTitleName = cursorCarerName.getString(cursorCarerName.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_FIRSTNAME)) + " " + cursorCarerName.getString(cursorCarerName.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_LASTNAME)) ;
        setTitle(carerTitleName + " is currently logged in");
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rotalist);
        textViewDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewdate);
        Log.e(TAG, "textview = "+textViewDate);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }// end of onCreate

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onBack pressed globaldatetime = " + nfcscannerapplication.getglobalDateTime());
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "global date in onresume getrota = " + nfcscannerapplication.getglobalDateTime());
        array = (ArrayList<String[]>)getIntent().getBundleExtra("rotaArrayBundle").get("rotaArray");
        Log.e(TAG, "array size in onresume = " + array.size());
        if(array.size() == 0){
            //then needname must be out of range, toast user with no rota available
        DateTime unavailableDate = nfcscannerapplication.getglobalDateTime();
        DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E dd MMM");
        String unavailStringDate = fmt2.print(unavailableDate);
        Log.e(TAG, "no rota!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GetRota.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("No Rota Available ");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Unable To View Rota For  " +"\n" + unavailStringDate);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                          onBackPressed();

                    } }); 

                alertDialog.show();

            }
            if (arrayAdapter == null){
                MySimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, array);

                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }
        }


        private MySimpleArrayAdapter getListAdapter() {

            return arrayAdapter;
        }

        public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

            dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datepicker1);

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        }

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menurotadetails, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.previous:


                DateTime dateTime = nfcscannerapplication.getglobalDateTime();
                DateTime dateTimeMinusOne = dateTime.minusDays(1);
                nfcscannerapplication.setGobalDateTime(dateTimeMinusOne);

                DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-Y");
                String previousDay = fmt2.print(dateTimeMinusOne);

                Intent i2 = new Intent(this, NfcscannerActivity.class);
                i2.putExtra("nextRota", previousDay);
                i2.setAction("NEXT_ROTA");
                startActivity(i2);

                return true;


            case R.id.next:

                DateTime dateTime2 = nfcscannerapplication.getglobalDateTime();
                DateTime dateTimePlusOne = dateTime2.plusDays(1);
                nfcscannerapplication.setGobalDateTime(dateTimePlusOne);

                DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-Y");
                String nextDay = fmt.print(dateTimePlusOne);

                Intent i = new Intent(this, NfcscannerActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("nextRota", nextDay);
                i.setAction("NEXT_ROTA");
                startActivity(i);

                return true;

            case R.id.today:
                setCurrentDateOnView();
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                return true;

            default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }


//adapter stuff...
```

.

In the calling class(NfcscannerActivity)

```
 Button getRota = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttongetrota);

            getRota.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onclicked getRota");






                    DateTime now = new DateTime();
                    nfcscannerapplication.setGobalDateTime(now);
                    Log.e(TAG, "now in getrota method in nfcact = "+ now);
                    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-Y");
                    String formattedNow = fmt.print(now);
                    String[] params = new String[]{nfcscannerapplication.getCarerID(), formattedNow}; 
                    AsyncGetRota agr = new AsyncGetRota();
                    agr.execute(params); 

                     }

                }// end of onclick
            });


some intent processing......
if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("NEXT_ROTA")){

            Log.e(TAG, "next rota action");
            String date = intent.getStringExtra("nextRota");

            getNextRota(date);
        } 



private void getNextRota(String stringExtra) {

    String[] params = new String[]{nfcscannerapplication.getCarerID(), stringExtra}; 
    AsyncGetRota agr = new AsyncGetRota();
    agr.execute(params);

    }



private class AsyncGetRota extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        Boolean isRotaArrayNull = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(NfcscannerActivity.this, 
                    "Connecting to Server"," retrieving rota...", true);


        };      


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "inside doInBackground");

                Log.e(TAG, "now in doinbackground = " + params[1]);
                rotaArray = nfcscannerapplication.loginWebservice.getRota(params[0], params[1]);
                //nfcscannerapplication.loginWebservice.getRota(params[0], params[1]);

               if (rotaArray == null){
                   Log.e(TAG, "about to call onstart");
                   isRotaArrayNull = true;
               }

            } catch (Exception e) {



               e.printStackTrace();


            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(progressDialog != null)
            progressDialog.dismiss();

           if(isRotaArrayNull == false){

            Intent intent = new Intent(NfcscannerActivity.this,
                            GetRota.class);
             Bundle b = new Bundle();
             b.putSerializable("rotaArray", rotaArray);

             intent.putExtra("rotaArrayBundle", b);
             startActivity(intent);
        }else{

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NfcscannerActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Signal Test");
            alertDialog.setMessage("No Phone Signal");

             alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                      onStart();
                } }); 



             alertDialog.show();

        }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

solved. I added the folowing to the manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".GetRota"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
```

I'm not 100% why this has made a difference but changing singleTop to singleTask has solved it